# Display MySql results using PHP (Dropdown Menu)

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a database that displays images for a portfolio which also have categorys (Fencing & Decking, Lining, Carparks etc).. I am trying to create a dropdown menu that will display only the selected category, with the default being 'all' images.. here's my code, can't seem to get it to work at the moment..

```
<?php

define('DB_NAME', 'wlarter_portfolio');
define('DB_USER', 'wlarter_user');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'pw');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

if (!$db_selected) {
    die('Can\'t use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysql_error());
}

$results= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM images") 
    or  die(mysql_error());

?>

<?php
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) { ?>

<div class="box-portfolio"> <?php echo $row['Img']; ?> </div>

<?php 
}; 
?>

<?php
   $category = isset($_GET['category']) && is_numeric($_GET['category']) ? $_GET['category'] : 1; // where 1 is a default category to show!
?>
<select onchange="if(this.value != '') document.location = '/portfolio.php?category=<?php echo $category; ?>&order_by=' + this.value">
  <option value="">Choose an option</option>
  <option value="Fencing & Decking"<?php if(isset($_GET['order_by']) && $_GET['order_by'] == 'Fencing & Decking') echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>>Fencing & Decking</option>
  <option value="Lining"<?php if(isset($_GET['order_by']) && $_GET['order_by'] == 'Lining') echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>>Lining</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You can do this in 2 ways: using PHP alone and by using AJAX. In the first one you will need to have your page reloaded to pass the `POST` value to the query, while in the 2nd, it's done using javascript so the page won't be reloaded.

Comment: Quentin - I will look into that
@ICanHasCheezburger - Which do you recommend to use? Could you possibly help me to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to rewrite your query. use this code:

```
$qry = "SELECT * FROM images ";
if(isset($_GET['category']) && is_numeric($_GET['category'])){
   $qry .=  "where category = ".$_GET['category'];
}
$results= mysql_query($qry) or  die(mysql_error());
```

Supposed you you have category_id column in your table. you can replace the name wh

Comment: Error on line 74 isset($_GET['category']) && is_numeric($_GET['category']){

Comment: from replacing the query i now receive an error on selecting from the drop down menu.. 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where category = 1' at line 1'

I apologize I am fairly new to php

Comment: @user3505895 sorry my mistake I have again edited the code plz check now.

Comment: Seems to have fixed the error but the results aren't showing when selecting the category, maybe its a mistake on my part, but the column name is 'category' so should work right?

Comment: @user3505895 hmm should work what values in that column depends on that.

Comment: My table consists of 'ID' 'Img' 'category' I have now seen that If I make the category field '1' it appears when I use the drop down menu but trys to order by "fencing & decking" or "lining", where as I want the category to be either f&d or lining, you follow?

Comment: @user3505895 Is your category column holding number or string value?